# if I am using caching on my website, where cached files are saved?

Tags: caching

I have this small technical question about caching...

I am planning to use caching for my website and I was wondering if the cached file where save on visitors personal computers !? 
I asked somebody and told me that they are saved on HTML files, and these are not on visitors Personal PC

Regards

Comment: are your webpages static or dynamic?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Caching can be done on various different levels. So there is no specific point, where files are stored. in every case.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you mean by Cache.  Most sites use caching to save bandwidth by reducing the hits to the database or other server resources by not having to re-generate dynamic content on every request.  On the other hand, browsers will cache JavaScript and CSS files  from websites on the local computer as a part of their normal process. Cookies are 'caching' important information specific to that computer / user and are also stored by the browser locally.

I am assuming that your talking about pages on a server, reusing them for multiple requests.  That can be stored as tmp files or as entries in a database on the server (CakePHP and CSP comes to mind here).  It really depends on your configuration and what you decide you want to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful information ... I am thinking of using W3 total cache plugin for that, I think that it is for reducing the hits to the database right? and has nothing to do with visitors local computers ??

Comment: another question and that will be it :) for the kind of caching that browsers use, it is related weather I have the caching plugin on my site or not, right? I mean it works alone as for browser function not related to my site ? thanks again